# Sum involving determinants of binomial coefficients, indexed by partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

I would appreciate some help proving a conjecture related to combinatorics and representation theory.

Given an integer partition $\lambda\vdash n$, define a polynomial in $N$ whose roots are the negatives of the contents of the partition,
$$ [N]_\lambda=\prod_{\square \in \lambda}(N+c(\square)).$$ This polynomial is closely related to the value of a Schur function evaluated at the $N\times N$ identity matrix. On the other hand, given $\nu\vdash m$ and $\rho\vdash k$ contained in $\nu$, Jacobi-Trudi applied to a skew-Schur function leads to a determinant of binomial coefficients
$$s_{\nu/\rho}(1_N)=\det_{1\le,i,j\le m}\left({N+\nu_i-i-\rho_j+j-1 \choose \nu_i-i-\rho_j+j}\right).$$ The final ingredient I need for my question is another determinant of binomials,
$$A_{\lambda\rho}=\det_{1\le,i,j\le k}\left({\rho_i-i \choose \lambda_j-j}\right).$$

Now, in the course of some physics calculation, I arrived at the quantity
$$ E_{\lambda\nu}(N)=\sum_{\lambda\subset\rho\subset\nu} A_{\lambda\rho}s_{\nu/\rho}(1_N).$$
I thought this was as far as I could push it, but experimentation convinced me that, as a function of $N$, this guy satisfies
$$ E_{\lambda\nu}(N)\propto [N]_{\nu/\lambda}.$$
It is very surprising to me that this sum should factor like this.

The question is how to prove the above conjecture.

For example, if $\nu=(2,2,1)$ and $\lambda=(1)$, the six terms in the sum are
$$\{\frac{1}{24}N(N^2-1)(5N-6),-\frac{1}{2}N^2(N-1) ,\frac{1}{3}N(N^2-1) ,\frac{1}{2}N(N-1),-N^2,N\}.$$ When all these are added, the result is proportional to $N(N-2)(N^2-1)=[N]_{(2,2,1)/(1)}$.

Actually, I think I know the proportionality constant when $\nu$ and $\lambda$ are both hooks:
$$E_{\lambda\nu}(N)= \frac{1}{(m-n)!}{m-n \choose m-n-\ell(\nu)+\ell(\lambda)}[N]_{\nu/\lambda}.$$

Comment: What is the actual question then in this case? It seems no "formal" question has been stated in the post....

Comment: An obvious but probably unhelpful suggestion is to try to put variables $x_i$ back into the equation.

Comment: Very vague comment. I wonder if your $E_{\lambda,\nu}$ comes from Cauchy-Binet applied to a minor of an appropriate product of matrices. Skew Schurs can be recognized as minors of a matrix (think Jacobi-Trudi). I think your $A_{\lambda\rho}$s can also be recognized as minors of an appropriate infinite matrix. Perhaps the product of matrices has nice structure.

Comment: If I didn't mess up, $A_{\lambda\rho}$ counts Molev's dual hook tableaux with shape $\lambda/\rho$ . Following Sam Hopkins' suggestion to put variables (two sets even) back might be good.

Comment: @Marcel: Molev's original article on double Schurs describes them. There is no determinant there though Gessel-Viennot would do. Anyhow, see equation 53 of Damir Yeliussizov's paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.01581.pdf for your determinant for $A_{\lambda\rho}$.

Comment: @user61318 Indeed, you are quite right and Lemma 9.1 in the paper you linked shows that my $E$ can be computed using an analogue of Cauchy-Binet. I would be happy to accept an answer with this content, if you want to write one.

Comment: @Marcel: OK! Does your claimed factorization follow though?

Comment: @user61318 Yes, the factorization follows. Let me know if you are going to write an answer (otherwise I will write one myself)

Comment: @Marcel: Great. Done.

Comment: See Problem 80 at http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ch7supp.pdf (version of 4 July 2020) and the solution at http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ch7suppsol.pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the OP's comment that the factorization can be obtained using my comments above, I repost them here.

The quantity $E_{\lambda\nu}(N)$ can be computed using Cauchy-Binet. Specifically see Lemma 9.1 in Yeliussizov's (nice) paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.01581.pdf.
For the quantity $A_{\lambda\rho}$, check equation 53 in loc.cit..